# Need help understanding closures

Tags: javascript, closures, frontend

I was understanding closure and tried to do some experiments and that's when I came across this problem.

When I execute code show below:

```js
    var hello;
    hello = 'abc';
    test();
    function test() {
       console.log(hello);
    }
```

output:
'abc'

now if I add another variable declaration inside the function then output is different

```js
    var hello;
    hello = 'abc';
    test();
    function test() {
       console.log(hello);
       var hello = 'xyz';
    }
```

Output: undefined

I'm not able to find out why it's behaving in this way. When test() function is executed it logs the variable 'hello' till now variable declaration inside test() function is not executed, so it should be give me global hello variable val but it returns undefined.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You should check out what `Javascript hoisting` does.

Comment: Variable declarations (the `var hello`) part are hoisted to the top of functions, but definition the `= 'xyz'` only happen where they are written. So your function gets an undefined, but declared, `hello` variable until you define it that shadows the one outside the function. It's a little weird at first.

Comment: you could limit your question into two lines of code: `console.log(data); var data = "data";`, and then your question would be a duplicate of so many others

Comment: @Adelin you have the reputation to vote this as a duplicate. If you know of so many duplicates, you should consider being helpful and posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the variable hello inside your function test is [hoisted](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes), which means that :

```
function test() {
   console.log(hello);
   var hello = 'xyz';
}
```

is actually the same as :

```
function test() {
   var hello;
   console.log(hello);
   hello = 'xyz';
}
```

Comment: In ES6 (variables declared with let/const appropriately) compiler/interpreter informs that something might be wrong, ex: `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'hello' before initialization`.